# How to convert rows into list using pandas python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

```
product,count,value1,value2,value3
A,10,5,3,2
B,8,2,2,4
```

This is my dataframe. I need output like following format:

```
product,count,values
A,10,[5,3,2]
B,8,[2,2,4]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way

```
In [27]: df['values'] = df[['value1', 'value2', 'value3']].values.tolist()

In [28]: df
Out[28]:
  product  count  value1  value2  value3     values
0       A     10       5       3       2  [5, 3, 2]
1       B      8       2       2       4  [2, 2, 4]

In [29]: df.drop(['value1', 'value2', 'value3'], axis=1)
Out[29]:
  product  count     values
0       A     10  [5, 3, 2]
1       B      8  [2, 2, 4]
```

Details:

```
In [35]: df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 10, 5, 3, 2], ['B', 8, 2, 2, 4]],
   ....:                   columns=['product', 'count', 'value1', 'value2', 'value3'])

In [36]: df
Out[36]:
  product  count  value1  value2  value3
0       A     10       5       3       2
1       B      8       2       2       4
```

Comment: Make sure, the `df` you're testing it on and you posted the question here are same. I've posted the dataframe used in solution, try that out.

Comment: ya now code is working this dataframe....but not working in another dataframe...it shows me the index error